# How to add transition from launch screen to initial view controller ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have two storyboards.

1. LaunchScreen.storyboard (has a simple LaunchScreen with a label)
2. Main.storyboard (Has one view controller(HomeScreen) with a label)

When the app loads, LaunchScreen shows and immediately presents HomeScreen with fade in transition.
Is there anyway I could change this transition?

I have tried following things

1. Set window?.rootViewController?.modalTransitionStyle in AppDelegate(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions).
2. Set window?.rootViewController?.transitioningDelegate.
3. Tried to add a custom view controller to LaunchScreen gives an error:"Launch screens may not set custom classnames".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new view controller that just shows the launch screen identically to how it looks when it's being launched.  Set that to be your initial view controller.  Transition from that view controller to your home view controller.

Comment: Thanks!
 I found another way by bringing launch screen view to front and then animate the view
 window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window!.addSubview(launchScreenView)
        window!.bringSubviewToFront(launchScreenView)